# Cannot access localhost/phpmyadmin because of https redirecting

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2.2

Im using redirecting with following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but now when i try to go to localhost/phpmyadmin instead i get https://application.company.com/phpmyadmin

How can i avoid this?

I want to be able to access phpmyadmin interface

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```